# Loop for creating headers and placing text into paragraphs below them

Tags: javascript, html

```
function newHeader (header) {
var head = document.createElement('h'+ header);
var hText = document.createTextNode('text for h'+ header);
head.appendChild(hText);
document.body.appendChild(head);
}

function newPara (para) {
var newP = document.createElement('p');
var newPText = document.createTextNode("text for p" + para);
newP.appendChild(newPText);
var intoH = document.getElementByTagName('h' + header);
intoH.item(0).appendChild(newP);
}

 for (i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
newHeader(i);
 }
 for (i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
 newPara(i);
 }
```

What am I doing wrong?
I want to dynamically create the headers and place paragraphs  with the text inside them. I was attempting to use the item() to appendChild to place the new paragraph text inside the headers accordingly but it doesn't work. I get the headers to show , but not the paragraph.

Please help!
thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `header` variable when is not defined (you should replace it by `para`), Also you miss `s` in `getElementByTagName` should be `getElementsByTagName` and that will return an array of elements so you can specify the first using `[0]` instead of `item(0)` :

```
document.getElementsByTagName('h' + para)[0];
```

Hope this helps.

---

```js
function newHeader (header) {
  var head = document.createElement('h'+ header);
  var hText = document.createTextNode('text for h'+ header);
  head.appendChild(hText);
  document.body.appendChild(head);
}

function newPara (para) {
  var newP = document.createElement('p');
  var newPText = document.createTextNode("text for p" + para);
  newP.appendChild(newPText);
  var intoH = document.getElementsByTagName('h' + para)[0];
  intoH.appendChild(newP);
}

for (i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
  newHeader(i);
}
for (i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
  newPara(i);
}
```

Comment: where would I define it since , its the name of the parameter in the function? I'm confused

Comment: wow. your awesome thank you!. But how did you know to place "+ para " in there and why?  Can you recommend any good books for DOM manipulation?

Comment: You're welcome bro, to detect such kind of errors you have to check the browser developpers console, for the book i don't have really a good suggestion :( , GOOD LUCK.